# Update stocks of existing product size on Add

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What's wrong with my code? The product stocks is updating but after I pressed the Add button and reload the page, the product that I added a stocks will be gone.

Here's my query:

```
if(isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
    $product_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn, $_POST['product_price']);
    $product_stocks = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn, $_POST['product_stocks']);
    $product_size =mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn, $_POST['product_size']);
    $product_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn, $_POST['product_id']);

    $search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct_extension WHERE product_size = '$product_size'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $search_query);
    $exists = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($exists) {
        $update_query = "UPDATE tblproduct_extension SET product_stocks = product_stocks + $product_stocks WHERE product_id = '$product_id' AND product_size = '$product_size'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $update_query);
    } else {
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO tblproduct_extension (product_stocks, product_price, product_size, product_id)VALUES('$product_stocks', '$product_price', '$product_size', '$product_id')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $insert_query);
    }
}
```

Ajax

```
//Show modal for adding size, price and stocks
function add_product_extension() {
    $('#product_add_extension').click(function(){
        var product_id = $('#product_id').val();
        var product_price = $('#product_price').val();
        var product_stocks = $('#product_stocks').val();
        var product_size = $('#product_size').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../admin/class.php',
            data: {product_id:product_id,product_price:product_price,product_stocks:product_stocks,
            product_size:product_size},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#addSize').modal('hide');
                show_products();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[image: tblprod]
[image: tblprod_ext]

Answer (score 0):

In select query you also have to specify product id. So for product you are searching, you will get correct result

So change

```
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct_extension WHERE product_size = '$product_size'";
```

to

```
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct_extension WHERE product_id = '$product_id' AND product_size = '$product_size'";
```

Comment: The problem is, once you add a stocks, size and price. The product will be gone.